# Integrate $\int_{0}^1 (1 + 4y^2)^{1/2} dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{0}^1 (1 + 4y^2)^{1/2} dy$$

So, how do I integrate this without the use of trigonometrical substitution? Can anybody give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Try $y=\frac{\sinh\theta}{2}=\frac{e^\theta-e^{-\theta}}{4}.$

Comment: COuld you develop where you got this ???

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You beat me to it by a few seconds, though of course one might object that this is cheating w.r.t. the prohibitions on trigonometric functions!

Comment: Given the hyperbolic Pythagoran theorem $\cosh^2 = 1+\sinh^2$ we have that such a substitution simplifies the integral.

Comment: @Travis: the primitive is related with the $\operatorname{arcsinh}$ function so there is no way of solving the integral without trigonometrical or hyperbolic trigonometrical (i.e. exponential) substitutions.

Comment: So, no cheat no win.

Comment: try $y=\frac{1}{2}\tan(t)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: *without the use of trigonometrical substitution*.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. Im gonna go try this!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the identity
$$
\cosh^2 u = \sinh^2 u + 1
$$

to simplify the square root; so, let
$$
\sinh^2 u = 4y^2 \to \sinh u = 2y  \to u = \sinh^{-1} 2y   \\
\implies \cosh u du = 2dy \\
\sqrt {1 + 4y^2} = \cosh u   \\
$$
from this you should be able to reoslve the integral.